# Дерево элементами которого являются символы

Tags: c++, дерево

В коде ниже создается бинарное дерево и заполняется случайными символами(цифрами и буквами верхнего и нижнего регистров), суть заключается в выводе из этого дерева только цифр и соответствующим им адресам.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int tabs = 0; 
//Ветвь
struct Branch
{
    char Data; 
    Vetka *Left;
    Vetka *Right; 
};

void Add(char aData, Vetka *&aVetka)
{
    if (!aBranch)
    { 
        aVetka = new Vetka;
        aVetka->Data = aData;
        aVetka->Left = 0;
        aVetka->Right = 0;
        return;
    }
    else 
    if (aVetka->Data>aData)
    { 
        Add(aData, aVetka->Left);
    }
    else
    { 
        Add(aData, aVetka->Right);
    };
}

// Вывода дерева
void print(Vetka *aVetka)
{
    if (!aVetka) return; 
    tabs++;

    print(aVetka->Left); 

    for (int i = 0; i<tabs; i++) cout << " "; 
    cout << aVetka->Data << endl; 

    print(aVetka->Right); 
    tabs--; 
    return;
}

void FreeTree(Vetka *aVetka)
{
    if (!aVetka) return;
    FreeTree(aVetka->Left);
    FreeTree(aVetka->Right);
    delete aVetka;
    return;
}


int main()
{
   Vetka *Root = 0;
   int n;
   cout<<"Введите ваш номер"<<endl;
   cin>>n;
   cout<<endl;
   n = 10 + 2*n;
   srand(time(0)); 
   char s[100];

    for(int i = 0; i < n;)
    {
        char ch = rand() % 127;
        if (isalnum(ch))
        {
            s[i] = ch;
            cout << s[i];
            ++i;
        }
    }

    cout<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++)
    {
        Add(s[i], Root);
    }

    print(Root);
    FreeTree(Root);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Очень интересно. А в чём ваш вопрос?

Comment: @VladD  ну я попытался как можно подробней объяснить в чем трудности, никак во не могу разобраться...

Comment: Ну могу сказать что в коде видимо у вас ошибка в обозначении (vetka -> branch) и если нужно вывести цифры, то в print() можно добавить проверку на число isdigit.

Comment: @vadosinferno я вот использовал isdigit и вышло что-то типа  `for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++)
 {
  if ( isdigit(s[i]) )
  cout<<s[i]<<" "; 
 }` и теперь мне не очень понятно, как вывести адрес этих элементов